# Fetching custom user field values in custom module

Tags: custom-field, jform

I'm having some problems with a custom module that I'm making to display some basic "logged in" user information.

I'm working on a template with "SP Page Builder" CMS.

**My module:**

```
{source}
<table style="width: 100%; border-top: 0px solid #bb141b !important;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: none !important;" width="84px">
            <img src="/images/2022/01/16/star-of-life-variant-colors-08.png" alt="nord-als-logo" width="70px">
        </td>
        <td style="border: none !important;" width="*">
            <strong><?php echo $user->name; ?></strong><br>
            <small>...</small>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{/source}
```

I would like to replace the "..." with the field value named `jform_profile_Stilling`.

I would also like to fetch the profile picture -- I found this label `jform_params_profilepic`.

Comment: Welcome @Mark and thanks for your question.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: What Joomla version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "custom module" are you trying to develop?

#### Joomla's default Module of type "custom"

An existing Module of module type "custom" to display custom HTML in your site. See https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_create_a_custom_module%3F
Such a custom module does not know anything about Joomla / users outside its module scope.

#### Programming your own Module

A Joomla module developed from scratch and install-able via the Joomla extensions installer. See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

In such a module you can do some database queries to get the information you want and display it on the screen. "SP Page Builder" is a commercial extension. I do not know how it exactly stores its information in the database.

Comment: Im trying to display information about the user who is logged in :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But what kind of Module are you trying to create? In Joomla back-end: Extensions > Modules > New > Type "Custom" (HTML). Or are you programming your own Joomla Module using PHP/MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I have a component that is using custom fields that are attached to the com_users component. The code I use is below.

```
$this->user = Factory::getUser();
$this->userFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', $this->user);
$this->fields = array();
foreach($this->userFields as $k => $field){
    $f = new stdClass();
    $f->title = $field->title;
    $f->value = $field->value;
    $this->fields[$field->group_title][] = $f;
}
```

After getting everything into the `$this->fields` array, I then just call the results where I need them. In my case, I am displaying the values as a part of a tab set.

```
<?php foreach($this->fields['YOUR_FIELD_GROUP_NAME'] as $fieldInfo){?>
    <div class="fieldLabel"><?php echo $fieldInfo->title;?></div>
    <div class="fieldValue"><?php echo $fieldInfo->value;?></div>
<?php }?>
```